# how to save and open your own file C#

Tags: c#, file-writing, file-read

When I press the save button in my program, I want to save a file with my own extension. (Example `.xyz`)

Then I want to open it and read the data inside it through this program.

How I can achieve this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When I press the save button in my program, I want to save a file with my own extension. (Example `.xyz`).
>   Do the following:

```cs
const string directory = @"D:\Temp"; // this can be any location you want

if (!Directory.Exists(directory))
    Directory.CreateDirectory(directory);

string path = Path.Combine(directory, "Test.custom");
if (!File.Exists(path))
{
    File.Create(path);

    // other logic
}
```

> Then I want to open it and read the data inside it through this program.

```cs
string textFile = @"D:\Torrent\Test.custom";

using StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(textFile);
var line = sr.ReadToEnd();
Console.WriteLine(line);
```

If you want later to save something in the file, the easiest way to do is this:

```cs
const string textFile = @"D:\Torrent\Test.custom";
string createText = $"Some text {Environment.NewLine}";
File.WriteAllText(textFile, createText);
```

Comment: Great, now I have one shortcoming. How do I write the data in this.

Comment: @İdrisBölge I've updated the post, please check.

Comment: Thanks :D it worked but How can I make it unreadable with notepad ..

Comment: @İdrisBölge via notepad you can try to open almost any file. So I don't know how you can prevent anyone to read your file that way unless uninstalling the notepad ;)

Comment: opps thanks anyway. I'd better open it later as a post.